# How to access https urls with oauth authentication in node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, oauth

I have a web application with REST APIs in JAVA. I want to trigger those REST APIs from a node.js application. The web application supports oAuth protocol. How can access such a application from Node. Do I require express to access it or will request module be enough. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of OAuth libraries for node:
For example:

Oauth:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth-client

Oauth2:
https://github.com/lelylan/simple-oauth2

Just use one of them to make your requests to the web application.